# Eclipse link database change notification

Tags: java, oracle, eclipselink, oracle-adf, change-notification

I have a java/j2ee application displaying data on UI connected to a Oracle database using Eclipse link.

I want the database to push data back to the UI in case of any changes.

Could I do a push change notification natively in eclipse link without my application having to poll the database for updated results?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Eclipselink user guide I googled http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/DatabaseEvents , the answer is yes.

Frank

Comment: How do I notify my java application using OracleChangeNotificationListener. How would the database notify me regarding which tables and rows have changed?